# How to return Multiple outputs from a database as different columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to access outputs from a database.

> Question : how many songs were released during each decade with classification of Pop music.
>   How exactly can I output all the songs in different decades in one single query search.

The desired output should be different columns with all the songs from different decades.

My try for the first two decades.

```
 Select count(*) as before1970 from Songs and classification = 'Pop' 
 Where ReleaseYear < 1970 and 
 (Select count(*) as 'before1980' from Songs 
 Where ReleaseYear BETWEEN 1970 and 1980 and classification = 'Pop' );
```

I checked the oldest song from the database is from 1969 so I used 1970 as a starter and then go up by each decade, But I get an output which returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative:

```
Select 
sum(if(ReleaseYear < 1970, 1, 0)) as before1970, 
sum(if(ReleaseYear >= 1970 AND ReleaseYear <= 1980, 1, 0)) as before1980 
from Songs where classification = 'Pop'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT 
     SUM(CASE WHEN ReleaseYear < 1970 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BEFORE1970,
     SUM(CASE WHEN ReleaseYear BETWEEN 1970 AND 1980 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BEFORE1980
    FROM Songs
    WHERE Classification = 'Pop'
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the GROUP BY clause, maybe let's calculate the decade of the song

`FLOOR(ReleaseYear/10) as Decade`

and then group by that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'before1970',FLOOR(ReleaseYear/10) as Decade FROM Songs 
WHERE classification = 'Pop' GROUP BY Decade;
```

maybe you can add some ORDER BY  if needed..

as I remember you need to set the decade calculation as a column so you can use it for the GROUP BY clause...

Comment: How can you declare the Floor ?